# resources.GetObject(xxx) returning Null instead of an empty list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on a windows form application and have a grid view on a form.  The form designer code is initializing the grid which has a property called "ReadOnlyColumns".  The property is a list of objects which are defined in a public class on the Data Grid View.

The code will compile, but when I try to load the form, the "ReadOnlyColumns" has been set to null by the designer.  I have other list properties which are properly set.  The property was properly set by the DataGridView to a new list, but the designer code on the host form is initializing it as NULL.  This is causing problems and although I can code around the null, it is not right.  The form properly initializes a list of strings as a list with zero objects.  Why can't it initialize a list of Custom Objects.

Below is code that works for a generic List, and code that returns null for the custom list.

Below Returns a list with zero objects - Correct.

```
this.dgvIndex.ColumnsToLower = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)(resources.GetObject("dgvIndex.ColumnsToLower")));
```

Below Returns a list that is null - Incorrect

```
this.dgvIndex.ReadOnlyColumns = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<ControlFactory.DataGridViewControlColumnProperties>)(resources.GetObject("dgvIndex.ReadOnlyColumns")));
```

dgvIndex.ReadOnlyColumns is a public property on the data grid, which is a new list when this code runs, even in the debuggers you can see that dgvIndex.ReadOnlyColumns is an empty list, not null.

Of course I did not write the designer code, but it is definitely causing problems.

Thoughts?

Comment: Winforms `DataGridView` doesn't have `ReadOnlyColumns`. Are you using some components library? More importantly, why do you accessing form resources *directly* (normally you shouldn't)? Regarding why value is `null`, in xml-serialization (which is used by winforms designer) properties with default values are **not** serialized (will not appears in resources). Does `ReadOnlyColumns` property has attribute `[DefaultValue(null)]`?

Comment: Is localization turned on?

Comment: Thanks Sinatr, this is a custom control we built that was based on the windows datagridview.  We are NOT accessing resources directly, but while debugging the code this was the source of null reference error.  For some reason, the fact that I have a property on this Grid View which is a customObject it is causing all sorts of issues.  For now, coded around the null return.

Comment: @RenniePet - Not sure what you mean by is localization turned on.

Comment: If you select the Form in the Visual Studio designer, one of the properties is Localizable. If that is set to True then many, many more of the properties of all of the controls in the form are written to the resources file, so they can be localized in alternative resource files. Don't know if that would make any difference, but just maybe.